# Ubuntu 16.04 - VSync not enabled, screen tearing

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, tearing

I'm using:

- GTX950M
- Integrated Intel Chipset Graphics from i7-6700
- Ubuntu 16.04

`glxgear` detects around 16000 fps.

These are my nvidia drivers:

```
aptitude search nvidia | grep ^i 
i   nvidia-361                      - NVIDIA binary driver - version 361.42     
i A nvidia-opencl-icd-361           - NVIDIA OpenCL ICD                         
i A nvidia-prime                    - Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime            
i A nvidia-settings                 - Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics d
```

This my nvidia-config:

```
#
#
# Configuration file for nvidia-settings - the NVIDIA X Server Settings utility
# Generated on Wed Apr 27 20:37:23 2016
#

# ConfigProperties:

RcFileLocale = C
ToolTips = Yes
DisplayStatusBar = Yes
SliderTextEntries = Yes
IncludeDisplayNameInConfigFile = No
ShowQuitDialog = Yes
UpdateRulesOnProfileNameChange = Yes
Timer = PowerMizer_Monitor_(GPU_0),Yes,1000
Timer = Thermal_Monitor_(GPU_0),Yes,1000
Timer = Memory_Used_(GPU_0),Yes,3000

# Attributes:

0/LogAniso=0
0/FSAA=0
0/TextureSharpen=0
0/TextureClamping=1
0/FXAA=0
0/FSAAAppControlled=1
0/LogAnisoAppControlled=1
0/OpenGLImageSettings=1
0/FSAAAppEnhanced=0
```

This my `glxinfo`:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/16093037/

And this my `xrandr`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080     60.01*+  59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       59.99  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   576x432       60.06  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   320x240       60.05  
DP-1 disconnected
HDMI-1 disconnected
HDMI-2 disconnected
```

And Xorg config:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "nvidia"
    Inactive "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "modesetting"
    BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
    Option "AccelMethod" "None"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "intel"
    Device "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
    Option "ConstrainCursor" "off"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Device "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "on"
    Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
EndSection
```

But I see a lot of tearing from chrome, videos, etc...

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I can't remember the link where I got these settings. I also have Intel i7-6700 but have a little newer GTX970M. After much trial and error these settings worked for me (with old settings commented out):

```
$ cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-nvidia.conf
Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver     "nvidia"
#    BusID      "PCI:1@0:0:0"
#    Option     "ConstrainCursor" "off"
    VendorName "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName  "GeForce GTX 970M:"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Device "nvidia"
#    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "on"
#    Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
#          Dec 14 2017 - Copy from /etc/X11/xorg.conf to /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-nvidia.conf
#                        Add options from: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA/Troubleshooting
    Option         "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {ForceCompositionPipeline=On, ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On}"
    Option         "AllowIndirectGLXProtocol" "off"
    Option         "TripleBuffer" "on"
EndSection
```

Comment: I have no more that laptop, so if anyone just confirms this works I'll mark it as correct.